How to send file inside json object
Maybe anyone know how to send request like this ?
{ 'NewDocuments':[ 
 { 
 'id':1,
 'document': (my image)
 }
]}

i need inside Json object send image (not in base64, but as file),
  data.files.add(MapEntry(
        'document',
        MultipartFile.fromBytes(
          bytes,
          filename: fileName,
          contentType: mediaType,
        )));

if i send like this is okey, but when it inside "NewDocuments" it is the problem. Maybe you have encountered such problem?
I use Dio package to send request.

If you want to upload files using a JSON, a multipart request is not the way to go: multiparts exists to upload files, not JSONs.
To actually send your file in a JSON, the better way to do so is to convert your file into a base64 string, essentially sending a stringified version of the document.
As an example, you can do as it follows
final String base64Doc = base64Encode(await doc.readAsBytes());

and convert each file into base64 string, put them into your JSON and send it in a POST request (I assume).

But if I want to send like this { 'NewDocuments':[
{
'id':1,
'document': (my image)
}
]}
let It be no in json, how to do it?
like in this format RequiredDocuments[0].applicantId: 331
RequiredDocuments[0].documentType: 1
RequiredDocuments[0].document: (binary)

As far as I can tell, you cannot achieve such behaviour without this JSON solution. Another way you could do, is make a multipart request for each file you have in your list, and you could put the applicantId into custom header parameters. I would advise to follow the separated multipart uploads because is more efficient (if you put all base64 docs in a JSON, it could be too slow to upload)

Have you tried this?
data.files.add(MapEntry("NewDocuments", [
    MapEntry("id", 1),
    MapEntry(
        'document',
        MultipartFile.fromBytes(
          bytes,
          filename: fileName,
          contentType: mediaType,
        ))
  ]));

Logically, this should work. Try it out

No unfortunately. It is not working, syntax is not right

Oh, In that case, I think it’s better to directly pass it as a JSON, and the Multipart file as a value for the key of document.

You can do like this
List<int> bytes = File('your_image.ext').readAsBytesSync();

FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
    'NewDocuments': [
      {
        'id': 1,
        'document': MultipartFile.fromBytes(
          bytes,
          filename: 'image.png',
          contentType: MediaType('image', 'png'),
        )
      }
    ]
});

Response response = await dio.post('endpoint', data: formData);


 


In that case it will be sent just as "Instance of Multipart"
